# ng-if is not working on page load

Tags: angularjs

I have a small Angular validation where I want an error to show if input has less than 3 charecters, or more than 6 charecters.

For what I have done, error is shown only when I start typing on the input, not otherwise, for example; if I load page and definitely on page load the input charecters are less than 3, so it should show error, but it shows error only when i start typing on input.

**my html:**

```
<form name="someform">
<input type="text" ng-model="handle"/>
<div ng-if="handle.length<lowcharec" class="alert" style="color: red">sorry, maxlength cannot be  less than 3
</div>
<div ng-if="handle.length>highcharec" class="alert" ng-init="highcharec" style="color: red">sorry, maxlength cannot be greater than 6
</div>
<input type="submit"/>

</form>
```

**my script:**

```
$scope.lowcharec = 3;
$scope.highcharec = 6;
```

I mam missing something and am new to angular, pls guide what i am doing wrong.

Comment: You have some typoe in your HTML.  furthermore ng-init="highcharec" won't do anything. finally it's always better to init varaible in controller : add a $scope.handle = [];

Answer (score 1):

That's because your `handle` variable is still undefined when the page loads (and remains so until you start typing in it), and `undefined < 3` evaluates to false. To fix this change your ng-if to `ng-if="handle.length<lowcharec || !handle"`.

Answer (score 0):

You are not showing complete code. So it is not easy to figure what is your actual problem. Here you can see a working example.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('FormCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.handle = '';
  $scope.lowcharec = 3;
  $scope.highcharec = 6;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app">
  <form name="someform" ng-controller="FormCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="handle" />
    <div ng-if="handle.length < lowcharec" class="alert" style="color: red">sorry, maxlength cannot be less than 3
    </div>
    <div ng-if="handle.length > highcharec" class="alert" ng-init="highcharec" style="color: red">sorry, maxlength cannot be greater than 6
    </div>
    <input type="submit" />

  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: thanks @niyasc, sorry for not showing the full code, but what walfrat  said is right. I didnot define $scope.handle=[]. Just did that, and it start showing me the error on page load